# Learning Python, trouble parsing certain values in JSON file

Tags: python, json

I'm doing my first ever project where in python and I decided to do it on Stardew Valley and their crops/price.

If some of you have played it before, you'd know that there are a few shops, sometimes 1 sells stuff the others do not.

my current json file i'm trying to parse through. my goal is to output only the purchase price values that don't have null.

```
"spring": [
    {
        "name": "Blue Jazz",
        "purchase_price":[
            {"Pierres's": 30,
            "JojaMart": 37,
            "Traveling Cart": null}
        ],
        "sell_price":[
            {"Base": 50},
            {"Silver": 62},
            {"Gold": 75},
            {"Iridium": 100}
        ],
        "is_multi_harvest": false
        
    },
    {
        "name": "Ancient Fruit",
        "purchase_price":[
            {"Pierres's": null},
            {"JojaMart": null},
            {"Traveling Cart": 1000}
        ],
        "sell_price":[
            {"Base": 550},
            {"Silver": 684},
            {"Gold": 825},
            {"Iridium": 1100}
        ],
        "is_multi_harvest": false
    }
]
```

my current code I got for it as of this moment is

```
def getcrops(season):
    print("CROPS")
    print("----------------------")
    for cropnames in crops[season]:
        if not "null" in cropnames["purchase_price"][0]["Traveling Cart"]:
            print(
                "CROP: {0:20} PRICE: {1}".format(
                    cropnames["name"], cropnames["purchase_price"]
                )
            )

getcrops("spring")
```

I have changed my if statement to

```
if cropnames["purchase_price"][0]["Traveling Cart"] is not None:
```

which is giving me my current error of

> if cropnames["purchase_price"][0]["Traveling Cart"] is not None:
> KeyError: 'Traveling Cart'

I'm sorry if this isn't making any sense, I am learning and wondering if maybe i'm writing my json wrong or trying to access the values in it wrong?

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong, but what’s less clear is how this ought to be indented. Don’t make us guess; please [edit] to fix this. (On the desktop version of this site, paste your program, select it, and type ctrl-K to properly format it as code.)

Comment: You are not parsing the JSON at all here. Presumably you are using the `json` module from the standard library to do that...? Please [edit] to provide a [mre].

Comment: What does `print(crops)` show you?  Are you seeing your data?  What about `print(cropnames)` _inside_ the loop, is that showing what you expect?

Comment: oh my apologies, I haven't used Stackoverflow all that much, i'll keep in mind the indenting issue. 
Again, I apologize for it.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```py
{"purchase_price":[
            {"Pierres's": null},
            {"JojaMart": null},
            {"Traveling Cart": 1000}
        ]
}
```

Is not a dict of a list of one dict, but a dict of a list of three dicts.  So if you access `purchase_price` you get this:

```
[{key: val}, {key: val}, {key: val}]
```

i.e. a list of dicts.  Which is less than helpful, but you can still get the object you want, either manually:

```py
travelling_cart = thing["purchase_price"][-1]["Travelleing Cart"]
```

(you tried this, but with the *first* entry, whereas it's the *last* entry.  This is assuming that you really do have three dicts, not one---which your 3rd has but your 1st doesn't.)

Which depends upon it always being the last entry in the dict, or more robustly:

```py
def get_by_key(k, l):
    for thing in l:
        if k in thing:
            return thing[k]
    return None # failed

get_by_key("Travelling Cart", thing["purchase_price"])
```

There are many other ways of writing that logic.

Comment: There's only _one_ entry in `purchase_price`.  Why would using `0` or `-1` make a difference?

Comment: @RocketHazmat there are three entries in all except the first instance.  Oops.  I'm going to clarify, but I'm guessing the OP made a typo---or else of course this isn't relevant

Comment: Oh!  Yeah, I didn't notice that!  I saw the 1st entry had a list with one element, I assumed the 2nd entry did, too.  Thanks for pointing this out :-)

Comment: so what i'm getting is I pretty much botched my JSON to make it harder on myself?

Comment: would a better way to write my JSON be something like this? (just doing the purchase price part):


    "purchase_price":{
        "Pierres's": 30,
        "JojaMart": 37,
        "Traveling Cart": null
    }

Comment: @ZacharyTurner if you are writing the json yourself, just write it all as one object (always).  If you are consuming the json from something else and it is in one format, handle that one format.  if you are consuming the json from something else and it is sometimes giving you a list of objects (dicts) and other times giving you one object, coerce it into one dict e.g. by `.update()`ing the first dict.

Comment: Yeah I am currently writing it all myself @2e0byo.
I'll make sure to change my JSON to this from now on. Apologies for any headaches given!

sorry again to everyone, i'm learning and don't really know how I should be using stack overflow.
I'll wait quite a bit long and keep testing before posting on here in the future.

Thanks for all the help people have been giving me for this

Comment: I don't think there's anything inherently wrong with posting a question early, it's more about posting it when you a. have a clear question and b. can't solve it and c. can't find any other solutions (and have tried).  In this case the answer to your question was 'you typed one lot one way and the other the other way' and had that been spotted earlier this question would *probably* be closed as 'caused by a typo'.

Comment: so following what you said @2e0byo and rewriting my json, I was able to get a more desired output, now to just isolate it so only the "seller" with a price gets outputed!

thanks for sharing that JSON tip with me :)